# GDALOpen return null on GEOTiff file

Tags: c++, gdal, geotiff

I'm trying to open GEOTiff image with gdal `library`. 
My code:

```
GDALDatasetH hSrcDS = GDALOpen("/home/gamma/srtm_55_01.tif", GA_ReadOnly);
if (hSrcDS == nullptr)
    printf("failure");
else
    printf("success");
```

And this is output:

```
ERROR 4: `/home/gamma/srtm_55_01.tif' not recognized as a supported file format.
failure
```

Also I tried using relative path but it didn't work too.

File `"/home/gamma/srtm_55_01.tif"` exists and was download from [here](http://dwtkns.com/srtm/) ([srtm_55_01](http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/wp-content/uploads/files/srtm_5x5/TIFF/srtm_55_01.zip)).

I thought maybe I'd made a mistake after all. I looked at the [sources gdal_contour](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/apps/gdal_contour.cpp#L284) and there the code is EXACTLY the same.

Moreover, I tried to use `gdal_contour` on my file - everything was successful.

```
gamma@gamma:~$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20
```

Comment: are you loading the GDAL Drivers? use GDALAllRegister() before open.

Comment: try to run gdalinfo srtm_55_01.tif to make sure that you called both `GDALAllRegister();` and     `OGRRegisterAll();` in your code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow the following order for opening the raster files

```
  /* register all known GDAL drivers.
   * attempt to suppress GDAL warnings.
   */

  GDALAllRegister();
  CPLPushErrorHandler(CPLQuietErrorHandler);
 /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 /*      Open source raster file.                                        */
 /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    GDALDatasetH hSrcDS = GDALOpen(pszSrcFilename, GA_ReadOnly);
    if( hSrcDS == nullptr )
        exit( 2 );

    GDALRasterBandH hBand = GDALGetRasterBand( hSrcDS, nBandIn );
    if( hBand == nullptr )
    {
        CPLError( CE_Failure, CPLE_AppDefined,
                  "Band %d does not exist on dataset.",
                  nBandIn );
        exit(2);
    }

    if( !bNoDataSet && !bIgnoreNoData )
        dfNoData = GDALGetRasterNoDataValue( hBand, &bNoDataSet );
```